# Notepad++ replace function character limit

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I am trying to replace a certain part of a file with a template which gets cut off when I paste all of it into the replace field and click replace.

My search is:

```
\t// MODDED STUFF HERE.*// END MODDED STUFF
```

And I'm trying to replace it with:

```
\t// MODDED STUFF HERE\r\n\t\r\n\trmCreateTrigger\("MyTrigger"\+1\);\r\n\r\n\trmSwitchToTrigger\(rmTriggerID\("MyTrigger1"\)\);\r\n\tfor\(i=1; <rmGetNumberPlayersOnTeam\(0\)\+1\)\{\r\n\t\tfor\(j=0; <10\)\{\r\n\t\t\t// Titan Shield\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",452\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Relic Eye of Horus\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",194\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\}\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\tfor\(j=0; <4\)\{\r\n\t\t\t// Acupuncture\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",562\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Temple of Healing\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",341\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\}\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\tfor\(j=0; <2\)\{\r\n\t\t\t// Thurisaz Rune\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",328\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Jade Rabbit\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",566\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Relic Head of Orpheus\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",196\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Relic Kithara of Apollo\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",201\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Relic Pelt of Argus\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",369\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Relic Oseberg Wagon\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",370\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\}\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Mythic Rejuvenation\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",432\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Heroic Renewal\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",433\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Hammer of the Gods\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",289\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Meteoric Iron Mail\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",290\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Dragonscale Shields\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",291\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Dwarven Mail\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",153\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Dwarven Weapons\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",155\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Relic Fetters of Fenrir\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",199\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\}\r\n\r\n\trmSetTriggerPriority\(3\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerActive\(true\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerRunImmediately\(true\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerLoop\(false\);\r\n\t\r\n\trmCreateTrigger\("MyTrigger"\+2\);\r\n\r\n\trmSwitchToTrigger\(rmTriggerID\("MyTrigger2"\)\);\r\n\t\r\n\trmAddTriggerCondition\("Timer"\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerConditionParamInt\("Param1",1\);\r\n\t\r\n\tfor\(i=1; <rmGetNumberPlayersOnTeam\(0\)\+1\)\{\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Grant Resources"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParam\("ResName","Food"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Amount",2\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Grant Resources"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParam\("ResName","Wood"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Amount",2\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Grant Resources"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParam\("ResName","Gold"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Amount",2\);\r\n\t\}\r\n\t\r\n\trmSetTriggerPriority\(3\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerActive\(true\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerRunImmediately\(false\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerLoop\(true\);\r\n\t\r\n\t// END MODDED STUFF
```

But part of that gets cut off. The reason I want to be able to replace it using the replace function rather than copying and pasting it directly is because I need to do the exact same replace for multiple files (over 30) so it would be much more efficient to do it by using the find and replace function instead of copying and pasting each time.

Is there any way to do it without part of the replacement text getting cut off by what I'm assuming is a character limit? Or if there is an alternative way to do what I need that isn't obscenely complex I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Using software such as Notepad++ and TextWrangler - as you pointed out - is limited in terms of the number of characters that you can paste inside the replace field.

You will have to use programing languages such as Python, PHP, etc. if you want to do this kind of replacing.

For example, You can do this in PHP using this code:

```
<?php
    $replace_text = $_POST['replace'];
    $target_text = ' \r\n\t\r\n\trmCreateTrigger\("MyTrigger"\+1\);\r\n\r\n\trmSwitchToTrigger\(rmTriggerID\("MyTrigger1"\)\);\r\n\tfor\(i=1; &lt;rmGetNumberPlayersOnTeam\(0\)\+1\)\{\r\n\t\tfor\(j=0; <10\)\{\r\n\t\t\t// Titan Shield\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",452\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Relic Eye of Horus\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",194\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\}\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\tfor\(j=0; <4\)\{\r\n\t\t\t// Acupuncture\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",562\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Temple of Healing\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",341\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\}\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\tfor\(j=0; <2\)\{\r\n\t\t\t// Thurisaz Rune\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",328\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Jade Rabbit\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",566\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Relic Head of Orpheus\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",196\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Relic Kithara of Apollo\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",201\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Relic Pelt of Argus\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",369\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t// Relic Oseberg Wagon\r\n\t\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",370\);\r\n\t\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\}\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Mythic Rejuvenation\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",432\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Heroic Renewal\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",433\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Hammer of the Gods\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",289\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Meteoric Iron Mail\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",290\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Dragonscale Shields\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",291\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Dwarven Mail\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",153\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Dwarven Weapons\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",155\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t// Relic Fetters of Fenrir\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Set Tech Status"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("TechID",199\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Status",4\);\r\n\t\}\r\n\r\n\trmSetTriggerPriority\(3\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerActive\(true\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerRunImmediately\(true\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerLoop\(false\);\r\n\t\r\n\trmCreateTrigger\("MyTrigger"\+2\);\r\n\r\n\trmSwitchToTrigger\(rmTriggerID\("MyTrigger2"\)\);\r\n\t\r\n\trmAddTriggerCondition\("Timer"\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerConditionParamInt\("Param1",1\);\r\n\t\r\n\tfor\(i=1; &lt;rmGetNumberPlayersOnTeam\(0\)\+1\)\{\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Grant Resources"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParam\("ResName","Food"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Amount",2\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Grant Resources"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParam\("ResName","Wood"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Amount",2\);\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\trmAddTriggerEffect\("Grant Resources"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("PlayerID",i\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParam\("ResName","Gold"\);\r\n\t\trmSetTriggerEffectParamInt\("Amount",2\);\r\n\t\}\r\n\t\r\n\trmSetTriggerPriority\(3\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerActive\(true\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerRunImmediately\(false\);\r\n\trmSetTriggerLoop\(true\);\r\n\t\r\n\t ';
    $replace_text = preg_replace("/(?<=HERE)(\.\*)/", $target_text , $replace_text);
    echo $replace_text;
?>
```

Save the PHP code above, and name it `a.php`.

Add another file to make the PHP work, This file will be `HTML` and copy the following code inside it, and save it as `a.html`

```html
<form action="b.php" method="POST">
Text: <input style="width: 500px; height: 80px; margin:5px; padding: 5px;" type="text" name="replace">
    <br /><br />
<input value="replace" style="margin:5px; width: 100px; height: 40px;" type="submit">
</form>
```

Now, run the a.html file in any localhost, and it should work!

This is the Regex that I used, you can change it - if you want - from the PHP file 'a.php' to fit your need.

```
(?<=HERE)(\.\*)
```